# How to apply table function to a list of vectors?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have the following code:

```
Permutation<-function(sequence,k)
{ 
   List <- list() 
   numberkmers <-length(sequence)-k+1
   for (i in 1:numberkmers)
   { 
    j <-i+k-1 
    kmer <- sequence[i:j]
    kmertmp <- sequence[i:j]
    kmer <-sort(kmer)
    perlist <-c()
    for (l in 1:k)
    {
      index <- which(kmer==kmertmp[l])
      perlist <- c(perlist,index)
    } 
   List[[i]] <- perlist
  }
  return(List)
} 
sequence <- qnorm(runif(1000),100,15) 
ListPer <- Permutation(sequence,4)
```

This code produce permutation based on the order of k numbers in a sequence i.e. if a sequence is `{39,12,40,18,20}` and `k=4` then the first permutation is 3,1,4,2 depending on the sorting order of `39,12,40,20` ..

I have two problems:

1. `ListPer` is a list of all permutations (i.e.vector) occurred in the sequence  and I would like to apply table function to all permutations in the list so the final result will be:

   > ```
   > P   : occur
   > ```
   >
   > 1,2,3,4:  34
   >
   > 2,3,4,1:  25
   >
   > 2,1,3,4:  15
2. Does the resulted table serves as a look up table so I can retrieve the number of occurrence of one permutation for any statistical analysis.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you could save some trouble by using `order(c(39,12,40,18,20)[1:4])` to get your 'permutation' values.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options using `table()`. You could concatenate the values and do a count

```
tt<-table(sapply(ListPer, paste, collapse=":"))
tt["2:1:4:3"]
# [1] 33
```

Or you could create a 4D array of counts

```
tt<-table(data.frame(do.call(rbind, ListPer)))
```

and then you could get counts out with

```
tt["2","1","4","3"]
# [1] 33
```

Note that these are character because 'table' indexes results with character vectors

Comment: Not that it's very difficult to convert `tt` with `as.numeric` :-)

Comment: `tt` itself contains numeric values, it's just the rownames and colnames that correspond to the uniquely observed levels are character values.

Comment: oops. Sorry 'bout that